# Parse Image Working in the emulator, not on the phone/tablet. i/o failure

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Code works perfectly on *emulator* but when deployed to a device it gives me:

```
ParseException @getData~ returns an "i/o failure" message.
```

Things I've tried and done:

- uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
- android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
- Also gave the permissions to the devices
- devices also have a working connection
- the Authentication Query works but when getting file/images returns null.

  ```
    final ParseQuery<ParseObject> plistQuery1 = ParseQuery.getQuery("HPProducts").orderByDescending("Price");
    plistQuery1.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Class_Parse cp = new Class_Parse();
                //Log.i("Here", cp.getProductImage(object));
                ParseFile parseFile = object.getParseFile("Image");
                parseFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null)
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //ivLogo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length));
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error at Image " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error at Query", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
  ```

Comment: What is the line that is throwing the error? Would you mind to share the way you are initializing Parse SDK?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo it throws at Parse Expection in done(). Then this is my Parse init
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .applicationId("myappID")
                .clientKey("client key")
                .server("server")
                .enableLocalDataStore()
                .build()
        );

Comment: Which of the done functions?

Comment: in getDataInBackground

Comment: Could you log and share what you have in the `parseFile` var?

Comment: Null in my mobile device, but in my emulator it contains "1538bee52a74a002e6ecc5099beddadb_image.png".

Comment: Exactly same file? Could you please double check? Are they both connecting to the same parse server instance?

Comment: Yes. I only have one parse server instance for this project.

Comment: Could you please check if the object id is the same in both scenarios? Also, have you tried to uninstall the app and install again? I can now only think that it can be a cache problem.

Comment: objectID is the same. I'll try uninstall and install. Update. still doesnt work but other queries without files work fine

Comment: Could you share the file url?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:1337/parse/files/myappID/1538bee52a74a002e6ecc5099beddadb_image.png

Comment: That's the problem. Your file url is pointing out to localhost. Check your publicServerURL configuration in Parse Server. You need to set it to the public dns of your parse server instance.

Comment: Thanks will try this.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo that is the solution thank you. But I cant seem to find the configuration within my app and or my Parse Instance. For now Im replacing localhost with the public DNS.

Comment: Could you share the code that you are using to initialize your Parse Server instance?

Comment: On my android code, I've already shared it here. I only have parse server on AWS.

Comment: I don't mean the SDK. I wanted to see the options you are passing to your Parse Server instance running on AWS during its initialization.

Comment: I'll try to look for this, as of now i don't know to to get this.